# Cognos SDK to get Database layer information for a data item

Tags: java, sdk, cognos

I am working with Cognos SDK for the last few weeks. I can able to get Data Item names, Expression details from Cognos XML reports. But I need to get Database layer information like underlying DB table and DB field info of the columns used in the reports. Is there any SDK available to get that? If not, please provide your guidance to get that.

Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 0):

You can query the content store database to search through the raw XML.  This can be useful for getting a list of all reports that reference a specific data source or column.

Here is an example of querying a cognos content store that lives on an Oracle database.  Replace 'cognos_cs' with the name of the schema you have your content store saved under.

```
SELECT     cmbase.NAME AS ObjName, cmo.PCMID, cmc.NAME AS ClassName, props7.spec
FROM       cognos_cs.CMOBJECTS cmo
JOIN       cognos_cs.CMOBJNAMES_BASE cmbase ON cmo.CMID    = cmbase.CMID
JOIN       cognos_cs.CMCLASSES cmc      ON cmo.CLASSID = cmc.CLASSID
LEFT JOIN  cognos_cs.CMOBJPROPS7 props7    ON cmo.CMID = props7.CMID
WHERE     cmo.CLASSID IN (10, 37)
  and upper(SPEC) like '%[SALES DETAIL]%'
ORDER BY cmo.PCMID;
```